HighCharts issue after angular upgrade
we have upgrade  from  angular 7 to 14 and using highcharts in the project.after moving to angular 14 few high charts related functionality  is broken . now we using "highcharts": "^11.0.1","highcharts-angular": "^3.0.0".now below code is  broken not sure what is the reason.
   ''' Angular code 
         import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import * as HC_exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
import * as HC_Local_Export from 'highcharts/modules/offline-exporting';

HC_exporting(Highcharts);
HC_Local_Export(Highcharts);
     ,,,  

Error -  This expression is not callable.
Type 'typeof import("c:/Users/KMWebApp/node_modules/highcharts/modules/exporting")' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

The code you shared is looking good. Could you please reproduce this issue in an online editor I could work on? Here's a basic demo template: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
